# Why was the statement "When You're White You Don't Know What It's Like To Be Poor" so controversial?

Tags: united-states, bernie-sanders

The statement: ["When You're White You Don't Know What It's Like To Be Poor"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCHfH0WABTY).

Why are so many people getting mad at Bernie Sanders for this?  I thought America was finally ready to move on from its racist past.  Why do so many white Americans have problems with acknowledging their white privilege?

Comment: This is an OK question, but the last two sentences should be omitted as it makes it more of a rant than a question.

Comment: Concurrence with @blip; starting a conversation by attacking the people that don't agree with you rarely goes well.

Comment: It's worth noting that not only does this statement preclude the possibility of poor white people, it precludes the possibility of wealthy non-white people.  Lastly, it precludes the possibility of someone to knowing or understanding something without directly experiencing it themselves at this moment in time.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - actually, it does neither.  It's a commentary on the relative perspectives, and how what is considered the experience of being "poor," relative to the norm for white people, is going to be very, very different from what is considered poor, relative to the norm for other groups.  Just like someone from the US who would be considered poor by anyone's US standards might not be considered especially down on their luck by someone in the Democratic Republic of Congo (average per capita GDP of under $400).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet No it's like saying that person from the Democratic Republic of Congo must implicitly know what it's like to be poor, and that a person from the US cannot know what it is like to be poor.  At the very least DNC and US have drastically different governments, aid programs and standards of living, but even then having a low income does not imply poverty without adjusting for factors like COL and cultural attitudes.

It doesn't really matter how you want to spin it.  Judging someones experiences and/or understanding by color of skin is racism 101.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - I don't see the words "all," "every" or "none" anywhere in there. It's pretty obviously a broad, general statement.  To claim that it's making very fine-tuned exacting scientific-precision representations is more than a little bit of a straw man.  ***For the most part,*** it's a very true statement.  This is 100% about judging someone's experiences based on their experiences.  In a society where racism is alive and well, that will often map to the color of their skin. That you seem to feel otherwise only illustrates the broader point being made about obliviousness to the realities.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet "For the most part, it's a very true statement. "  Based on what evidence?  Please, show me a study that indicates that whites have no *knowledge* of what it's like being poor?  Otherwise, admit you assume that purely based on racist tendencies.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - so, explain how, if a white person experienced one set of circumstances in regular life, and someone else did not, how would the white person be *expected* to know about that? Do you dispute that whites and blacks report different perceptions about equity, attribution of cause, and acknowledgement that disparate racial treatment even exists?  It objectively does, so if whites don't acknowledge it, for the most part, do you need anything more than that?

Comment: I'll be happy to pull up those kinds of studies and statistics, but I want to make sure that meets the criteria now, as opposed to having you hand-wave it away after I meet your request.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - Did you even bother reading any of the answers, below?  A couple of them talk about the context of the speech and the place of this statement within that context - a context you seem to be pretending doesn't exist.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet " how would the white person be expected to know about that?"  That sounds like something that's worth looking into.  Clearly humans are able to share information to each other, and are able to use this to handle events and make decisions about things they've never personally encountered before.  Furthermore why assume a white person *hasn't* experienced a set of circumstances?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60020/discussion-between-poloholeset-and-npsf3000).

Answer (score 31):

The controversy is mainly focused on the validity of his statement when it comes to whites and blacks in poverty, not necessarily racism.

**There are actually far more poor whites in the U.S. than poor blacks.**

These are the statistics on Americans living in poverty from 2014, the most recent data from the Census Bureau:

- Whites (Non-Hispanic): 19.7 million
- Hispanics: 13.1 million
- **Blacks: 10.8 million**
- Asians: 2.1 million

***BUT:*** the share of blacks in poverty (26.2%) is much higher than the share of whites (10.1%). That was probably what Bernie Sanders meant in his statement.

But the controversy was that there are certainly many whites who know what it's like to be poor.

Comment: This is also making the same mistake of taking the quote out of context. You need to listen to the entire quote. (however, that is also the answer to the question...people take quotes out of context)

Comment: @blip What do you mean?

Comment: Your answer is focused purely on wealth...which is not what at all the full quote was getting at. The full quote was getting at issues of racism. Your answer isn't *wrong* it's just that it's pointing out the snippet of the quote that was taken out of context.

Comment: @blip The context doesn't change the meaning. While it is true that Mr. Sanders was talking about the difficulties faced by blacks in America, he still included "what it's like to be poor" in a list of things white people don't know. The other items in the list aren't the question here. But the statement that whites don't know what it is like to be poor is demonstrably false.  If I said "Dogs, cats, mice, Irishmen, hamsters and bears walk on all fours and can't learn to read", the context that I was correct on 4 of the things I said wouldn't excuse my claim about Irishmen.

Comment: @readin context *always* changes meaning.

Comment: @blip The context didn't make this any better.  Sanders should've said "when you're wealthy" rather than "when you're white".  By saying it as he did, he turned it from a humanitarian expression of concern for those suffering from poverty to a racially charged falsehood.

Comment: @nat no, because you're completely ignoring context. But, whatever,

Comment: @blip Actually I read the articles and the surrounding speech.  You might disagree with people who find Sanders's comments to be tone-deaf, but you can't honestly claim that people who watched the speech in-context to be ignoring the context that they saw.  At most, you can disagree with their conclusions.  It'd probably help if you explained your position to people rather than just tell them that they're wrong; even if we disagree with how you see it, at least that's communication, ya know?

Comment: @nat if your read the entire quoted talk, then you're willfully disregarding the context. The entire speach was about the challenges faced by poor black people. Which in no way implies poor white people do not exist. FYI, I explained my position quite clearly in my answer.

Comment: @blip I think that you're willfully disregarding the objectionable content that others are seeing.  We get the good part about what Sanders was trying to say; just, he also revealed something quite ugly in his choice of words too.  We see the good in what he said; do you see the bad in it?

Comment: @blip I wouldn't say something ugly about his intentions so much as his worldview.  But, I understand your point that, to you, it's not a big deal - that only his larger message matters and that people shouldn't look too far into how he said it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59480/discussion-between-blip-and-nat).

Comment: @Nat: Even "when you're wealthy" excludes those of us who were once poor, but are now wealthy - or at least prosperous.  The real cause of controversy is that Sanders has let his ideology blind him to reality.

Comment: It's not very useful presenting absolute numbers if the base quantities you compare them to are different. The **But** part should be on top of the answer. Would make it much better.

Answer (score 21):

At the heart of it, it is an inaccurate statement that presupposes all white people are wealthy. This ignores the multitude of white individuals that are poor.

According to [The Henry J. Kaiser Family Foundation](http://kff.org/other/state-indicator/poverty-rate-by-raceethnicity/), there are more white people beneath the poverty line than black people beneath the poverty line.
19,796,700 > 10,145,200

In its full context:

> "When you're white, you don't know what it's like to be living in a ghetto," Sanders concluded. "You don't know what it's like to be poor. You don't know what it's like to be hassled when you walk down the street or you get dragged out of a car. And I believe that as a nation in the year 2016, we must be firm in making it clear, we will end institutional racism and reform a broken criminal justice system."

The response is very absolutist, a collection of statements that negate any misfortune suffered by white individuals. At the foundation, it is an endorsement of the mythic 'white privilege argument."

There are white people that live in the ghetto. There are poor white people. There are white people that are routinely hassled by the police.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36666/discussion-on-answer-by-drunk-cynic-why-was-this-statement-so-controversial).

Comment: I don't see how white privilege is 'mythic'. I am white myself and though I live below the poverty line, I do not have to deal with many of the social issues specifically associated with skin colour. I have lived in a very high crime, very 'ghetto' area several times, and I have experienced many forms of discrimination, but I would not presuppose to understand the particular and unique experience of those who happen to be born with darker skin.

Comment: This answer, while factual, only scratches the surface of the latent racism and out and out subversive and destructive identity politics that liberals trade in.

Comment: @KDog The intention of the quote is not of concern with the question, just the controversy about quote. Establish your narrative elsewhere.

Comment: @DrunkCynic The intention is part of the reason the quote is controversial.  It goes beyond the stupidity of the factual points.  The Democrats' platform or position is that certain groups should always be favored over other groups, no matter the circumstances or facts on the ground.

Answer (score 4):

It's controversial for the same reason that nearly every Facebook political meme is controversial: It takes a quote out of context and implies that there was a much different meaning than what was intended.

The snippet that is being quoted on Facebook is meant to imply that Bernie Sanders doesn't believe white people can be poor.

However, if you listen to the entire quote, he's clearly talking very specifically about poor black urban youth.

Yes, white people can certainly be poor, and grow up in neighborhoods if not called ghettos, certainly akin to them. But white people don't typically have to deal with the entire list of issues that Bernie Sanders pointed out...namely the constant harassment one has to deal with due to skin color.

**It's controversial because people like to react to things sans context**

To be fair, this is how politics often works...taking quotes out of context and paint the opponent in a much different light than was intended by the full quote.

If I were running for office I might say "I don't like children being left behind by society" but you can bet there's be a Facebook Meme of me quoted as saying "I don't like children" :)

Comment: The statement doesn't include any qualifiers, such as 'typically,' existing as an absolute blanket statement.

Comment: @DrunkCynic which part do you feel needs the 'typically' qualifier? Also, notice that it *does* use that qualifier.

Comment: Yes, your Answer applies a qualifier to his statements, yet no where in his comment did he qualify the statements he was making. He claims, absolutely, that white people don't know what it is like to live in the ghetto, be poor, or be hassled by the police.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Oh! Well, that's part of the whole context thing. It's an arbitrary (and often purposeful) assumption that people that don't add qualifiers to every statement don't believe that they are applicable. Political statements, much like advertising, PR, and the like often skip the qualifiers to simply make their message more direct.

Comment: The recent example is how "black lives matter" has been distorted by groups who have attempted to imply that the statement really is "*only* black lives matter". In fact, in this case, they are *adding* a qualifier that wasn't there. This is, for the most part, just part of how political spin works. It's part of the sport.

Answer (score 0):

That is a single sentence from a broader statement taken out of context.

The context Bernie was speaking about was being black.  There are intersections between being black and poor that are different than being white and poor.  A white kid, a black kid, and a Hispanic kid all growing up on the west side of Detroit will have very similar life experiences, but the perception of those experiences will be different because each kid is viewing their experiences through their own, racial, lens.  A poor white kid from Detroit crossing into Dearborn to buy groceries with foodstamps may receive different reactions in the checkout line than the poor black kid.

Maybe the other people in the checkout line would be black and someone would tell a joke about even white folks being poor and on foodstamps as a critique of the larger economy.  That comment will affect the white kid differently than another comment from a white crowd in the checkout line if it was the black kid buying groceries.  The white kid may feel socially alienated because the comment he heard implies that white kids shouldn't be poor.  The black kid would feel differently if the comment he heard reaffirmed a nasty stereotype of his racial group.

Bernie Sanders did not say white people could not be poor.  Nothing from the context Bernie was speaking from suggests that he was alluding that white people can't be poor.  If other people are saying that Bernie said "White people can't be poor", the other person is adding that into what Bernie said.

Comment: While this is a good explanation of what Sanders *meant*, it doesn't address the question, which is "Why is it controversial?".

Comment: @Bobson the answer is in the first sentence.

Comment: @blip - If so, then the other three paragraphs are irrelevant fluff and the answer itself is a duplicate of yours.  I don't disagree with that statement - it was *very much* taken out of context.  I just think that this particular answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Bobson that's fair.

Answer (score -7):

Sanders probably spends his entire life in a bubble and is projecting himself.

Roughly speaking, half of the US military are poor whites. They are intelligent and conscientious in terms of job performance. And, from a bystander's point of view, what strikes you the most is the undeniable fact that these beings are sentient - or, in layman's term, they are warm blooded full men - they walk around with the kind of natural warmth one seldom witnesses in "polite society."

They are extremely dumb due to the lack shrewdness, and extremely credulous to such extent that everyone is preprogrammed with a set of moral codes that are inimical to their own well-being. In other words, they are poor because they are all masochists.

America is a country where one is free to screw himself. Evolution favours the psychopathic trait; poor whites are doomed for the lack of it.